# Hive query not using index

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am analyzing the impact of using an index on hive table. I created a table with 5 columns (`COL1`,`COL2`,`COL3`,`COL4`,`COL5`) and loaded 100000 rows in it. I also created an index on COL1 on this table.

I ran `select *` with `WHERE` clause on `COL1` which is an index column.

I see no improvement in query run-time compared to when I ran the same query before creating the index.

I did an EXPLAIN on my select query and it shows TableScan instead of IndexScan and I am unable to figure out why it's not using the index.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can check [this](http://maheshwaranm.blogspot.com.tr/2013/09/hive-indexing.html) and [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201205.mbox/%3C60367909.283357.1337221656873.JavaMail.root@sms-zimbra-message-store-03.sms.scalar.ca%3E) but basically it is as following;

1. Create the index

   CREATE INDEX .. ON TABLE...
2. Build the index

   ALTER INDEX .. ON .. REBUILD;
3. Use the index

   INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/tmp/indexes/..' SELECT `_bucketname`, `_offsets` FROM default__t_..__...

   SET hive.index.compact.file=/tmp/indexes/x;

   SET hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.HiveCompactIndexInputFormat;

   SELECT ... from ... where ... group by ...;

Hope it helps