# Hive not using indexes created

Tags: hive

I have created an index on one of the text format hive table.

But if I query the table using 'where' filter seems indexes are not being used by query engine, as I don't see any diff in query response time with or without index. Even query plan is not showing indexes use.

The version of hive which I am using is 0.13 and I alreday set hive.optimize.autoindex value to true.

is there a way to figure out why the hive is not considering the indexes?..

Comment: Please check the answer provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37303433/1290868). Hope it helps.